# Foreign Key off of a UNIONed View

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a view that looks like this:

```
CREATE view   reference.Test WITH SCHEMABINDING  as

    SELECT        reference.HighlevelTestId as TestId, Name, IsActive,
                  cast(1 as bit) as IsHighLevelTest 
    FROM          reference.HighlevelTest

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        LowLevelTestId  as TestId, Name, IsActive, 
                  cast(0 as bit) as IsHighLevelTest  
    FROM          reference.LowLevelTest

GO
```

NOTE: HighLevelTestId and LowLevelTestId are guaranteed to never have the same values (no conflicts).

I have another table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Reference].[TestAddition](
    [TestId] [BigInt] NOT NULL,
    [OtherStuff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    .... 
)
```

I would really like to FK my `TestAddition` table to my `Test` view on the TestId column (for referential integrity and ease of use with OData).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe `CHECK CONSTRAINT` as a function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx is sufficient? For referential it is.

Comment: Seriously?  "FK Off ..."?  You might want to rephrase that.

Comment: I can't think of a way to fake a primary key on a view that contains a union, but that does not prevent you from joining to the view.  It just means that you will manage referential integrity yourself and not rely on the database to do it.  You've already said "HighLevelTestId and LowLevelTestId are guaranteed to never have the same values", so you're halfway there :)

Comment: Just how are HighLevelTestId and LowLevelTestId guaranteed to never have the same values?  Why is it two tables?

Comment: @Blam - The HighLevelTestId and LowLevelTestId values are generated from business data that does not overlap.  They are two different concepts (one usually owns the other), but they are sometimes treated as a single "Test" concept (as in this situation).

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Wow, how did I not see that?  Thanks for the tip.  I changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys cannot be applied to views. Get it from this angle: You cannot apply referential integrity to results simply returned by `SELECT` statement, because they are not stored permanently, they are just a non-persistent output of a query.

To manage referential integrity, apply foreign keys or other such constraints to data while you have stored them permanently - in your case for example in tables `IsHighLevelTest` and `IsLowLevelTest`. Or make result of your `UNION` permanent by storing it in a table. There is more ways.